# Insert JSX with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to insert the following piece of JSX into my mark up but I get back an [object, Object] once it has been inserted. How can I place this piece of JSX into my div ?

Function which is called to insert JSX:

```
   placeInDiv = (arr) => { 

    if (this.arrowRef.current !== null) {
      this.arrowRef.current.innerHTML = <div className={`${this.sliderData.length === 5 ? 'd-xl-none' : ''} arrow-container`}>
          {arr[0] == true &&
          <img onClick={() => this.setDirection("previous")} className="arrow-left" src={ArrowRight} /> }
          {arr[1] == true &&
          <img onClick={() => this.setDirection("next")} src={ArrowRight} /> }
        </div>
    }

  }
```

Markup:

```
<div className="ggg" id="arrows" ref={this.arrowRef}>
</div>
```

having great difficulty working this out please help.

Here is the full block of code demonstrating what I am trying to achieve. As you can see the function is called within the render and passed specific params.

FULL CODE BLOCK:

```
import Carousel from 'react-elastic-carousel';
import top from '../images/top.png';
import ArrowRight from '../images/arrowRight.svg';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class contentSlider extends Component {

  state = {
    disabled: '',
    leftArrow: false,
    rightArrow: true
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    
  }


  arrowRef = React.createRef();

  sliderData = [
    {
      title: 'POLO',
      typeOfcontent: 'Mens T-Shirt',
      rrp: '£105',
      ourPrice: '£55',
      salePrice: '£45',
      image: top
    },
    {
      title: 'POLO',
      typeOfcontent: 'Mens T-Shirt',
      rrp: '£105',
      ourPrice: '£55',
      salePrice: '£45',
      image: top
    },
    {
      title: 'POLO',
      typeOfcontent: 'Mens T-Shirt',
      rrp: '£105',
      ourPrice: '£55',
      salePrice: '£45',
      image: top
    },
    {
      title: 'POLO',
      typeOfcontent: 'Mens T-Shirt',
      rrp: '£105',
      ourPrice: '£55',
      salePrice: '£45',
      image: top
    },
    {
      title: 'POLO',
      typeOfcontent: 'Mens T-Shirt',
      rrp: '£105',
      ourPrice: '£55',
      salePrice: '£45',
      image: top
    },
    {
      title: 'POLO',
      typeOfcontent: 'Mens T-Shirt',
      rrp: '£105',
      ourPrice: '£55',
      salePrice: '£45',
      image: top
    },
    {
      title: 'POLO',
      typeOfcontent: 'Mens T-Shirt',
      rrp: '£105',
      ourPrice: '£55',
      salePrice: '£45',
      image: top
    }

  ]

  breakPoints = [
    { width: 2, itemsToShow: 2, itemsToScroll: 2 },
    { width: 550, itemsToShow: 3, itemsToScroll: 3},
    { width: 850, itemsToShow: 4, itemsToScroll: 3 },
    { width: 970, itemsToShow: 4, itemsToScroll: 3 },
    { width: 1150, itemsToShow: 5, itemsToScroll: 3 },
  ] 

  setDirection = (slideDirection) => {
    switch(slideDirection) {
      case "next":
        this.carousel.slideNext();
        let slideNext = document.getElementById('slider-move');
        
        if(slideNext.classList.contains('test-right')) {
          slideNext.classList.remove('test-right');
          slideNext.classList.add('test-left');
        }
            
      break;
      case "previous":
        this.carousel.slidePrev();
        let slidePrevious = document.getElementById('slider-move');
        
        if(slidePrevious.classList.contains('test-left')) {
          slidePrevious.classList.remove('test-left');
          slidePrevious.classList.add('test-right');
        }

      break;
    }
  }

  getAmountOfPages = (pages, activePage ) => {

    let firstItem = pages[0];
    let [lastItem] = pages.slice(-1);
    let array = [];

    if(firstItem === activePage) {
      array.push(false, true);
      return array;
    } else if(lastItem === activePage) {
      array.push(true, false);
      return array;
    } else {
      array.push(true, true);
      return array;
    }
  }

  placeInDiv = (arr) => { 

    if (this.arrowRef.current !== null) {
      ReactDOM.render( this.arrowRef.current.innerHTML = <div className={`${this.sliderData.length === 5 ? 'd-xl-none' : ''} arrow-container`}>
          {arr[0] == true &&
          <img onClick={() => this.setDirection("previous")} className="arrow-left" src={ArrowRight} /> }
          {arr[1] == true &&
          <img onClick={() => this.setDirection("next")} src={ArrowRight} /> }
        </div>, this.arrowRef.current)
     
    }

  }

  render() {  
    return (
      <div className="content-slider-wrapper">
        <div className="content-slider-title">
          <span>PRODUCTS OF THE WEEK</span>
        </div>
        <div className={`${this.sliderData.length === 5 ? 'mt-xl-5' : ''} content-slider-container`}> 
          <div className="test-right" id="slider-move">
            <Carousel 
                ref={ref => (this.carousel = ref)}
                breakPoints={this.breakPoints} 
                disableArrowsOnEnd={true}
                renderPagination={({ pages, activePage, onClick }) => {
                  let arr;
                  arr = this.getAmountOfPages(pages, activePage);

                  this.placeInDiv(arr);
                  return (
                    <>
                      <div className={`${this.sliderData.length === 5 ? 'd-xl-none' : ''} black-slider-container`}>
                        {pages.map(page => {
                          const isActivePage = activePage === page
                          return (
                            <div className={isActivePage ? 'black-slider' : 'blank-slider'}
                              key={page}
                              onClick={() => onClick(page)}
                              active={isActivePage}
                            />
                          )
                        })}
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )
                }}
                >
                {this.sliderData.map((item, index) => (
                  <div key={index} className="carousel-item-container">
                    <div className="carousel-image-container">
                      <img src={top} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="carousel-text-container">
                      <ul>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-title">{item.title}</li>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-text">{item.typeOfProduct}</li>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-text line-through">RRP {item.rrp}</li>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-text line-through">Our Price: {item.ourPrice}</li>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-text">Sale Price: {item.salePrice}</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </Carousel>
          </div>
        </div>   
        <div className="ggg" id="arrows" ref={this.arrowRef}>
<p>dasda</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default contentSlider;
```

Comment: why are you wanting to do it with `innerHTML` react has much better ways of doing that.

Comment: I cant do it via state, because the place in which the function is called will emit a infinite loop. What other ways do you suggest? surely there is just a simple solution to insert jsx dynamically

Comment: Mb it will be better if you create a new component and pass your arr as a prop?

Comment: You probably should be using state combined with `useEffect`, but its hard to tell without knowing the context of your problem.

Comment: that wont work, first I need to use a class based component and secondly I am calling the function within the render() so setting state via this means would cause an infinite loop. I can post the full code if that helps.

Comment: "first I need to use a class based component" — Then use component did mount instead

Comment: That wont work because the function has to be called within the render and then passes specific params to it. You cant do this via on mount

Comment: I have added the full code block for clarity and to provide a better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting the JSX to be interpreted or just rendered as is (as a string)? Because the innerHTML DOMstring value is parsed by the browser and it doesn't handle any JSX transpilation. That is handled by Babel before your JavaScript reaches the browser.

But I believe you might be able to use the `ReactDOM.render()` function, supplying your JSX as first argument and `this.arrowRef.current` as second argument.

Note that ReactDOM is a separate package you need to import.

```
const div = <div className={`${this.sliderData.length === 5 ? 'd-xl-none' : ''} arrow-container`}>
          {arr[0] == true &&
          <img onClick={() => this.setDirection("previous")} className="arrow-left" src={ArrowRight} /> }
          {arr[1] == true &&
          <img onClick={() => this.setDirection("next")} src={ArrowRight} /> }
        </div>

ReactDOM.render(div, this.arrowRef.current)
```

Comment: Yes this was my beliefs that it would be interpreted as a string. I need the JSX to be interpreted not rendered as just a string. can you please provide an example. something like this i guess ReactDOM.render(b, this.arrowRef.current)

Comment: this dont work as i am getting ReactDOM is not defined

Comment: Not sure if this works. But even if it does it's probably not the right approach since it kind of defeats the purpose of using React. Couldn't you just change this to a component instead, and pass it `sliderData` etc as props:` `<div className="ggg" id="arrows" ref={this.arrowRef}>`?